# Replace all spaces in a certain part UNIX

Tags: unix, sed

Hi all I'm trying to replace all spaces beginning in certain part of my file. I tried to do it but I can't make it to start in a certain part.

i tried this `sed "s/\s/_/g" < file.txt > file_1.txt` but all of the spaces turn into underscore.

inside `file.txt` :

```
My Name
Favorite Food
Favorite Color
Time is gold
List of Dogs:
Shi ba Inu
Sibe rian Husky
Labra dor Retriever
Ger man Shep herd
Bull Doge
Be agle
chi hua hua
Bull Ter rier
```

expected `file_1.txt`:

```
My Name
Favorite Food
Favorite Color
Time is gold
List of Dogs:
Shi_ba_I_nu
Sibe_rian_Husky
Labra_dor_Retriever
Ger_man_Shep_herd
Bull_Doge
Be_agle
chi_hua_hua
Bull_Ter_rier
```

Comment: can you specify the reason why rows 7 and above can only have spaces replaced by underscore/no-space? Is it because of `:`

Comment: Explain "in certain part of my file".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the substitution to happen only after "List of Dogs", try

```
sed -e '1,/List of Dogs:/b' -e 's/\s/_/g'
```

The command `b` means "branch" (to the end of the script, i.e. bypass the substitution) and the address range specifies this action for the first line through the first line matching the regex.

Comment: Your problem statement is extremely obscure so this is based on qualified guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the substitution happen only after the `:`, use something like this:

```
sed -r  '/:/,$ s/\s/_/g;' file.txt > file_1.txt
```

The substitution is restricted from a line containing `:` until the end of the file `$`.

Comment: i tried it but List of dogs got included in the underscore. thanks tho

Answer (score 1):

Given your initial input `file.txt`:

```
My Name
Favorite Food
Favorite Color
Time is gold
List of Dogs:
Shi ba Inu
Sibe rian Husky
Labra dor Retriever
Ger man Shep herd
Bull Doge
Be agle
chi hua hua
Bull Ter rier
```

You can try this:

```
$ sed '/List of Dogs/,$s/\s/_/g;s/List_of_Dogs/List of Dogs/g' file.txt
```

Which results:

```
My Name
Favorite Food
Favorite Color
Time is gold
List of Dogs:
Shi_ba_Inu
Sibe_rian_Husky
Labra_dor_Retriever
Ger_man_Shep_herd
Bull_Doge
Be_agle
chi_hua_hua
Bull_Ter_rier
```

### Explanation

- `sed` commands can be split by `;`
- first part starts with getting an address, which is the form `range start,range end`. Finds the line that `List of Dogs` starts at. And `$` specifies last line of file, for the `range end` part of this syntax
- so just for this address range, your search and replace command is done: `$s/\s/_/g`
- but unfortunately the command also replaced and resulted in `List_of_Dogs:` so second command `s/List_of_Dogs/List of Dogs/g` is just a workaround to convert it back

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer and you don't know it =)

You say you want to replace the spaces, but you have not said what you want to replace them with. I suspect, you want to replace them with a no-space character, right?

```
sed "s/ //g" $original_file > $new_file
```

or referencing the space with \s the following should also work

```
sed "s/\s//g" $original_file > $new_file
```

The syntax is basically

```
sed "s/find_this/replace_with/g" $original_file > $new_file
```

I hope that helps...

Comment: That's what I thought at first, too, but it's not at all what the example suggests.

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple, obvious, robust, portable, etc. and just use awk:

```
$ awk 'found{gsub(/[[:space:]]/,"_")} /:/{found=1} {print}' file
My Name
Favorite Food
Favorite Color
Time is gold
List of Dogs:
Shi_ba_Inu
Sibe_rian_Husky
Labra_dor_Retriever
Ger_man_Shep_herd
Bull_Doge
Be_agle
chi_hua_hua
Bull_Ter_rier
```